# Creating a UIButton inside a subView programmatically not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to add a UIButton inside a UIView called containerView. The containerView is showing normally but the UIButton isn't showing up at all. This is my code:

```
  let containerView = UIView()
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    self.containerView.frame =  CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 100, y: 200, width: 225, height: 70)
    self.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    self.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.containerView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.view.addSubview(self.containerView)

    let button1: UIButton = UIButton()
    button1.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 70, y: 200, width: 35, height: 35)
    button1.clipsToBounds = true
    button1.setTitle("Tesing Button", for: .normal)
    self.containerView.addSubview(button1)
   }
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you test putting x and y origin for your button to 0 and see what happens?

Comment: Your container view is 225 wide and 70 tall, and you are putting your button at an x value is that is probably outside the view, and y (200) that definitely is.

Comment: Try setting the x and y to be half the width and height to see if the coordinates you put in simply won't work. This is done by self.view.frame.size.width /2

Comment: Ah it's taking the coordinates relative to the container view! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button frame is positioned incorrectly. You have set the value of `y` as 200 which is beyond the size of your container view.